# Losing current selection when calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview

I have expanded list view, which contains 15 items, when i reaches to the bottom i load 15 more. When i get the 15 more, i called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() , then list moves to the top, so lost my current selection. I wanted, list should add more but it should goes to bottom, my selection stat should not be changed, like gmail app. They added new items at bottom silently. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could get the currently selected object and re-set it after the notify.

Comment: Do you recreate the adapter or just add new items to a previous one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `selectionMode` of your `ListView` to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`.

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

By default `ListView` has a `CHOICE_MODE_NONE`. Setting it to either `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` will keep your selected item(s)'s state.

You can read more on this topic in [Android Developers' article about Touch Mode](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html)

Comment: +1 when calling notifyDataSetChanged() my list view was jumping to the top every time - using single choice mode stopped this. Thx